# Azure Media Services v3 - Event Grid - deleting asset doesn't trigger any storage events

Tags: azure-media-services

Azure Media Services v3 - Event Grid - deleting asset **doesn't trigger any storage events**.

**Goal is to use Event Grid to detect asset changes** like asset created or asset deleted.

**Is there a way to get events for the asset blob containers themselves and not the individual blobs?**

Many Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated events are sent during a live event - actually too many for what I need.

Only deleted events are sent only for the deletion of the live event preview blobs: preview.ism & preview.ismc blobs.

```
  {
"topic": "/subscriptions/123/resourceGroups/ResGroup/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/my_storage",
"subject": "/blobServices/default/containers/asset-90fc157d-b4a3-4862-a7fe-ff4df7fa5ee7/blobs/preview.ismc",
"eventType": "Microsoft.Storage.BlobDeleted",
"eventTime": "2018-12-05T06:38:32.997468Z",
"id": "e8416467-b01e-00a3-2965-8ccf53060fe2",
"data": {
  "api": "DeleteBlob",
  "clientRequestId": "05549d31-e9be-4f15-961f-befbba482f6c",
  "requestId": "e8416467-b01e-00a3-2965-8ccf53000000",
  "eTag": "0x8D65A7C46CFD798",
  "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
  "contentLength": 3809,
  "blobType": "BlockBlob",
  "url": "https://my_storage.blob.core.windows.net/asset-90fc157d-b4a3-4862-a7fe-ff4df7fa5ee7/preview.ismc",
  "sequencer": "0000000000000000000000000000137600000000003f399c",
  "storageDiagnostics": {
    "batchId": "06e102aa-d2ec-4aaf-8c4c-0d89dfae5ffb"
  }
},
"dataVersion": "",
"metadataVersion": "1" }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, according to the offical document [Reacting to Blob storage events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview), as below.

> Blob storage events are available in general-purpose v2 storage
>   accounts and Blob storage accounts.

So if you were using general-purpose v2 storage, only created events `Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated` will be sent to your event subscription for Azure Storage. Please make sure which kind of Azure Storage you used.

Secondly, if only focus on asset deleted events `Microsoft.Storage.BlobDeleted`, you can select it from `EVENT TYPES` in your Event Subscription of Azure Storage like the figure below.

[image]

All Blob Storage Events are related to blobs themselves, not containers. There is [`Filtering events`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview#filtering-events) feature which you can see in the tab `Additional Features` to 
match events with subject begins or ends string, but also still get events for asset blobs.

[image]

A workaround way is to process the blob events via webhook to filter, or you can try to combine EventHubs with StreamAnalytics to filter and get events for containers.

Comment: *Don't you think its wierd that deleting an asset leads to no storage events?*

Account is StorageV2 (general purpose v2)

My hope is that event grid can replace polling with the Media Services API.  However if deleted assets trigger no events then polling is still required.